# How can I get ALSA library functions to work in Apache CGI?

Tags: linux, apache2, cgi

The following code prints out available ALSA Midi cards; by default there should always be at least one.
However, when accessed through Apache CGI, the snd_card_next() function does not work properly, resulting in the first if statement being activated and no ALSA cards being found.

Why is Apache CGI somehow not able to process this function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

#define NL  "\r\n"

void get_alsa_midi_cards(void)
{
    int card, status, cnt;
    int code;
    char *card_name;
    int i;
    
    card = -1;  // use -1 to prime the pump of iterating through card list
    status = snd_card_next(&card);
    if (status < 0 || card < 0) {
        printf ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" NL "Cache-Control: no-cache" NL NL);
        printf("{\"alsa_midi_card\":[]}");
        //printf("Status: %i Card: %i", status, card);
        //printf("Status: 404 Not Found" NL NL);
        return;
    }   
    printf ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" NL "Cache-Control: no-cache" NL NL);

    printf("{\"alsa_midi_card\":[");

    for (i = 0, cnt = 0; card >= 0; i++) {
        if ((code = snd_card_get_longname (card, &card_name)) < 0)
            continue;
        if (cnt++ > 0)
            printf(",");    
        printf("{\"longname\":\"");
        printf(card_name);
        printf("\"}");

        if ((status = snd_card_next (&card)) < 0)
            break;
    } 
    printf("]}");
} 

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    get_alsa_midi_cards();

    return 0;
}
```

Note: To compile code with gcc, add the -lasound flag.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache user, usually www-data, needs to be added to the 'audio' group in order to access this function.

```
usermod -a -G audio www-data
```